# Detecting whether the card is present or not in a smart card reader

Tags: arduino, smart-card

Recently I bought a [32320 Smart Card Reader](http://www.parallax.com/Portals/0/Downloads/docs/prod/rf/32320-SmartCardReader-v1.0.pdf). I had no trouble making the circuit, but I could not figure out what command to use to tell if the card is in or not. Any ideas?

Comment: No, because we don't know what a "32320" is!

Comment: Do you have a link to the datasheet? (and no, the linked document is not a datasheet)

Comment: In the linked document, you have the CD pin. Did you try using it? It should provide card presence information.

Comment: Pin 2 = CD = Card Detect changes when card is inserted. Read it.

Answer (score 2):

The code examples for the card reader is well hidden on their site. Nice products. hard to find docs.   Look for the smart card code examples.
[image]

And dont worry if you dont give us enough information, It was hard for me to find it too.

```
**'' Define Smart Card connections  
' allows non-contiguous pin usage  
  cd := cdpin 
 dira[cd] := 0 
 pub detect | ok 
'' Detects insertion and presence of Smart Card  
  if (ina[cd] == 1)               ' inserted?  
    start                         ' check card  
   ok := (write($A0) == ACK)  
   stop  
  else  
  ok := false  
 return ok  *
```

http://obex.parallax.com/objects/649/

[image]
http://www.parallax.com/Portals/0/Downloads/docs/prod/rf/32320-SmartCardReader-v1.0.pdf